# Malloc inside a structure

Tags: c, pointers, struct, malloc

I've just started a course about C programming and I'm stuck with the malloc() function.
I've a code to implement a linked list of segments.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct{
  struct {
    double x, y;
  } point;
  void *next;
  void *prev;
} segment_t;

typedef struct {
  segment_t *first;
  segment_t *last;
} poly_t;
```

Now, if I want to allocate the memory for the struct `segment_t`, should I allocate also the memory for the two void pointers `*next` and `*prev`?
And the same for `*first` and `*last` inside the poly_t structure?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: No, `malloc` only the new nodes. The pointer members point to other nodes (which are already allocated), or you set them to `NULL` when they don't point anywhere, for example the last link in a chain.

Comment: Aside: `void *` can be used as a "universal" object pointer type, but for type-safety it would be better to use a specific pointer type. However, to do that, you need to define your `struct` with a tag name. For example `typedef struct segment segment_t;` `struct segment {` `struct {` `double x, y;` `} point;` `segment_t *next;` `segment_t *prev;` `}`;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`malloc(sizeof(segment_t))` allocates enough memory for the entire structure, including `x`, `y`, `next` and `prev`.

It doesn't initialize any of those members, however. If you want `next` and `prev` to point to something, you will need to assign a pointer to them. Whether it's a freshly allocated pointer (`malloc(...)`) or an existing one (incl `NULL`) is up to you.

In this particular case, an instance of `segment_t` is a node of a doubly-linked list. As such, `s->next` and `s->prev` should be initialized to `NULL` until the node (segment) is added to the list.

---

As mentioned by @Vlad from Moscow, you shouldn't be using `void*` for the pointers, but the following:

```
typedef struct segment {
  struct {
    double x, y;
  } point;
  struct segment *next;
  struct segment *prev;
} segment_t;
```

Comment: Ok, so if I'm building the function to set up a new segment, is it better to do like this:
`segment_t *segment_new(double x, double y) {
  segment_t *s = malloc(sizeof(segment_t));
  s->next = malloc(sizeof(segment_t));  
  s->prev = malloc(sizeof(segment_t));  
  s->point.x = x;
  s->point.y = y;

  return s;`

or like this: 
`segment_t *segment_new(double x, double y) {
  segment_t *s = malloc(sizeof(segment_t));
  s->point.x = x;
  s->point.y = y;

  return s;` ?
Thanks

Comment: `s->next->x`, `s->next->y`, `s->next->next`, `s->next->prev`, `s->prev->x`, `s->prev->y`, `s->prev->next` and `s->next->prev` are all uninitialized after that. It makes no sense to create three segments and leaving two of them uninitialized. You probably want `s->next = NULL; s->prev = NULL;`

Comment: If I was building a linked list, I wouldn't have a `segment_new` function at all. I would pass the data (not a node/segment) to the insert/append/whatever function. That function would allocate the node/segment and assign the parameter to the newly-created structure, setting `prev` and `next` as appropriate to add it to the list.

Answer (score 1):

For starters it is unclear why within the structure the pointers have the type void *. This only confuses readers of the structure definition

```
typedef struct{
  struct {
    double x, y;
  } point;
  void *next;
  void *prev;
} segment_t;
```

Whether you mean

```
typedef struct{
  struct point{
    double x, y;
  } point;
  struct point *next;
  struct point *prev;
} segment_t;
```

or you mean

```
typedef struct segment {
  struct {
    double x, y;
  } point;
  struct segment *next;
  struct segment *prev;
} segment_t;
```

So change the structure definition accordingly to its usage.

If you want to allocate memory for an object of the type `segment_t` or `poly_t` then the object should be initialized ultimately. For example the pointers next, prev, first, and last initially can be initialized by NULL.

Comment: A comment indicates the pointers are to segments. so it's the latter. 100% agree that `void*` shouldn't be used here.

Comment: @ikegami It is just a bad idea to use void * as the type of the pointers. This only confuses readers of the code.

Comment: I agree it's a bad idea, but this is the first part of an homework set up by the professor.